# How can i place featured image after h2

Tags: images

i want my featured image after first paragraph under first H2.
please tell me a code which i can place in functions.php

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Please show us your research efforts. What have you tried already? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: It differs from theme to theme. This question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Like @fuxia said; please show us all code you have tried yet. Did you code a fresh theme? Or are you editing the files of an existing theme in Wordpress? Give us (lots) more info so we can help you!